# Why does android graphics paint has 1.5 scale factor

Tags: android

I try to draw a line with the width depending on the density.
The problem is that I can not make setStrokeWidth() method paint the width I want.
Here is the code:

```
...    
private void init(){
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);        
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);    
    }

@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), 0, paint);        
    }
...
```

The above code displays a line with 2px width both on mdpi and hdpi screens.
How can I make paint to draw the line with the specified width?
Where does 1.5 scale factor come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are drawing at the absolute top of the canvas, making only half the line visible, that is why it ends up 2 px wide. To see the entire line, move it down a bit.

To create a density dependent value you can use the following code:

```
float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int sizeInDp = (int) (desiredWidthInPx*scale + 0.5f);

paint.setStrokeWidth(sizeInDp);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have you found this solution empirically or there is hint somewhere in the documentation?

Comment: It is briefly mentioned at this page at Android Developers (look at the *Density-independent pixel* part): http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
But I think I got the complete formula from some other question on SO.